# Styling Feed Content returned in XML Format

Tags: php, xml, dom, xslt

I have this code that is pulling info from my database and then checking it against an API. I'm trying to customize the return information into a table. I'll include a picture to show what I would like. I've searched everywhere and I don't know how to code this. Don't worry about the CSS it's just getting the information to fill a table.

```
<?php
        $key = "********************";
        $address = urlencode($CustomFields->field('jr_address',$listing,false,false));
        $city = $listing['Category']['title'];
        $zip = $CustomFields->field('jr_zipcode',$listing,false,false);
        $url = "http://api.greatschools.org/schools/nearby?key={$key}&address={$address}&city={$city}&state=MI&zip={$zip}&schoolType=public-charter&levelCode=elementary-schools&minimumSchools=50&radius=10&limit=5";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);      
        curl_close($curl); 
        print_r($response);
?><style type='text/css'>gsId{display:none;}name{color:#9BB055; font-size:18px;}type{display:none;}gradeRange{}enrollment{}gsRating{}city{display:none;}state{display:none;}district{}districtNCESId{display:none;}address{display:none;}phone{display:none; }fax{display:none;}ncesId{display:none;}lat{display:none;}lon{display:none;}</style>
```

The Return Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<schools>
<school>
<gsId>6350</gsId>
<name>Chinese Education Center</name>
<type>public</type>
<gradeRange>K-5</gradeRange>
<enrollment>63</enrollment>
<gsRating>3</gsRating>
<city>San Francisco</city>
<state>CA</state>
<district>San Francisco Unified School District</district>
<districtNCESId>0634410</districtNCESId>
<address>657 Merchant St., San Francisco, CA  94111</address>
<phone>(415) 291-7918</phone>
<fax>(415) 291-7965</fax>
<ncesId>063441005596</ncesId>
<lat>37.795</lat>
<lon>-122.4042</lon>
<overviewLink>http://www.greatschools.org/california/san-francisco/6350-Chinese-Education-Center/?s_cid=gsapi</overviewLink>
<ratingsLink>http://www.greatschools.org/school/rating.page?state=CA&amp;id=6350&amp;s_cid=gsapi</ratingsLink>
<reviewsLink>http://www.greatschools.org/school/parentReviews.page?state=CA&amp;id=6350&amp;s_cid=gsapi</reviewsLink>
</school>
<school>
<gsId>6389</gsId>
<name>Gordon J. Lau Elementary School</name>
<type>public</type>
<gradeRange>K-5</gradeRange>
<enrollment>667</enrollment>
<gsRating>7</gsRating>
<city>San Francisco</city>
<state>CA</state>
<district>San Francisco Unified School District</district>
<districtNCESId>0634410</districtNCESId>
<address>950 Clay St., San Francisco, CA  94108</address>
<phone>(415) 291-7921</phone>
<fax>(415) 291-7952</fax>
<website>http://www.gjles.org/</website>
<ncesId>063441005599</ncesId>
<lat>37.794</lat>
<lon>-122.4086</lon>
<overviewLink>http://www.greatschools.org/california/san-francisco/6389-Gordon-J.-Lau-Elementary-School/?s_cid=gsapi</overviewLink>
<ratingsLink>http://www.greatschools.org/school/rating.page?state=CA&amp;id=6389&amp;s_cid=gsapi</ratingsLink>
<reviewsLink>http://www.greatschools.org/school/parentReviews.page?state=CA&amp;id=6389&amp;s_cid=gsapi</reviewsLink>
</school>
</schools>
```

I don't know how to write the script to make it look like this:
Link to image:
[link text](http://www.landcontractgr.com/images/Screenshot.jpg)

---

So the new file looks like this?

```
<?php
    $key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $address = urlencode($CustomFields->field('jr_address',$listing,false,false));
    $city = $listing['Category']['title'];
    $zip = $CustomFields->field('jr_zipcode',$listing,false,false);
    $url = "http://api.greatschools.org/schools/nearby?key={$key}&address={$address}&city={$city}&state=MI&zip={$zip}&schoolType=public-charter&levelCode=elementary-schools&minimumSchools=50&radius=10&limit=5";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);      
    curl_close($curl);
    echo (xml2html($response, "/xslt/schools.xsl");
```

?>

I get an error on the echo line.

Where does this go?

```
<?php
function xml2html($xmldata, $xslPath)
{
    /* $xmldata -> your XML */
    /* $xsl -> XSLT file */

    $arguments = array('/_xml' => $xmldata);
    $xsltproc = xslt_create();
    xslt_set_encoding($xsltproc, 'ISO-8859-1');
    $html =
        xslt_process($xsltproc, 'arg:/_xml', $xslPath, NULL, $arguments);

    if (empty($html)) {
       die('XSLT processing error: '. xslt_error($xsltproc));
    }
    xslt_free($xsltproc);
    return $html;
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe an XML document with more than one schools will be more helpful. Also, there is latitude and longitude for each school, but what are the coordinates of the point to which the distance from the school should be calculated? This is not specified in your question.

Comment: I've included another school in the code above. As far as the latitude and longitude, I don't know if you saw the image (At the bottom of original post) that I posted. I would just be hiding it. When I send the address info to the API it sorts which schools are closer. My challenge is that my knowledge is very limited and I'm lost as how to code any of this.

Comment: To see it live click here: 

http://www.landcontractgr.com/component/content/article/113-jenison/96-7681-thomas-ave 

then it's the education tab

Comment: Not about XSLT stylesheet or language, but specific XSLT processor integration with PHP. Rettaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are unable to visualize custom XML (i.e. your schools xml). 
So you should manually transform it to HTML. I know 2 solutions:

1. Parse XML with [xml parser functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php)
2. Transform XML by XSLT sheet (as for me, better approach).

For offerred XML I've written next XSLT: [link text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L5mCzRqrRq7xw_J5dvY0i_65wiC7m9e8rdqW84uRHio/edit?hl=ru) (sorry for external link, I  have unexplainable troubles with pasting XSLT code here)

Transformation could be applied by the function [xslt_process](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xslt-process.php). (You should store xsl file somewhere in your server's folder (for example "xslt/schools.xsl") and convert xml response):

```
<?php
function xml2html($xmldata, $xslPath)
{
    /* $xmldata -> your XML */
    /* $xsl -> XSLT file */

    $arguments = array('/_xml' => $xmldata);
    $xsltproc = xslt_create();
    xslt_set_encoding($xsltproc, 'ISO-8859-1');
    $html =
        xslt_process($xsltproc, 'arg:/_xml', $xslPath, NULL, $arguments);

    if (empty($html)) {
       die('XSLT processing error: '. xslt_error($xsltproc));
    }
    xslt_free($xsltproc);
    return $html;
}

// making request...
$response = curl_exec($curl);      
curl_close($curl);
echo(xml2html($response, "/xslt/schools.xsl"));
```

?>

Comment: Hey Alex, I appreciate your speedy response although I'm not sure how to code this. Due to my limited knowledge I'm stuck. I have a live version of the code. 

The Link:
http://www.landcontractgr.com/component/content/article/113-jenison/96-7681-thomas-ave

I'm not asking for anyone to code the whole thing. It's just I don't know how to get it so where I can have a table and call certain fields into a cell to make everything look how I want it.

Comment: Hi Carl. Your link above leads to some house sale proposition. So I don't actually understand your problem. You should get response as xml document from service. Then use PHP function xslt_process for transformation from XML to HTML with help of XSLT file, that I've attached above. The result of transformation will be standart HTML table. Then you could colorify rows with CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, it's under the education tab. I don't know how to code the xslt_process in to the script. Also I don't know what I need after the code to get the HTML Output. For example <td><name></td>

Comment: Check out original post at top. I'm getting an error on the echo line and I don't know where to add in the <?php function... script.

Comment: Of course, you are getting error. I've forgotten ")" in string echo(xml2html($response, "/xslt/schools.xsl")). You should place function xml2html($xmldata, $xslPath){...} before the line 'key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";'. Have you ever read any articles dedicated to PHP?

Comment: @alex zhevzhik: You wrote *"Browsers are unable to visualize custom XML"* and that's not true. CSS stylesheet (as well as XSLT stylesheet, of course) are aviable for browsers since... at least 10 year ago. CSS' standard complaint vary between browsers: in particular `display: table-cell;` in this case.

Comment: @Alejandro: Of course, you are right. I meaned that browsers are unable visualize JUST xml (i.e. without css or xsl).